# Which uk olive oil can I buy is really early harvest extra virgin olive oil?

Tags: oil

I want to buy early harvest extra virgin olive oil, however, it seems there is no way to know what is the real thing.  Searching suggests supermarket brands have been tested and failed to be extra virgin olive oil, and those that passed were Californian.

I’m in the UK and want to buy EVOO; do I have to buy from California or is there a brand I can trust?

Comment: Early harvest is labelled in Spain as "Cosecha Temprana"

Comment: Apparently the labels don’t prove anything hence the question

Comment: Try going to a specialty store instead of a supermarket